# Making Format String with sprintf

Tags: c, format, printf

I want to create a format string that will be used in `scanf` by specifying a `MAX_LENGTH` for a string input. What I have is the following but the compiler says it's wrong:

```
const int MAX_LENGTH = 50;
char format[9];

sprintf(format, "\%%d[^\n]s", MAX_LENGTH);
```

The compiler says that the data argument is not used by the format string. The first `%` should be escaped, and the second one is part of the `%d` which should be read in from `MAX_LENGTH`. How do I accomplish this? By the way, the format string should read at most `MAX_LENGTH` characters until a newline is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The % sign should be escaped here using `%%`, *not* `\%`.

Comment: Just to make sure, it's valid to use ``scanf(format, input)`` where ``format`` is ``"%50[^\n]s"`` and ``input`` is ``char [50]``?

Comment: No, the maximum number of characters is one less than the size of the receiving array.  Also the `s` is the format is useless.  The actual solution is `snprintf(format, sizeof format, "%%%d[^\n]", MAX_LENGTH-1);